# how to plot multiple pictures with pylab in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have the following code:

```
import psycopg2
import pylab


class Datenanzeige:

def __init__(self):
    self.conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' user='test' host='test' password='test'")
    self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    self.site = ['FFF', 'PPP', 'DDD', 'KKK']
    self.plant = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


def anzeige(self):

    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(6):

            self.datProd1 = []
            self.datProd2 = []

            self.cur.execute(""" 
                    SELECT proddate, Sum(mods) AS Summevonmods 
                    FROM "20091229global" 
                    GROUP BY proddate, site, plant, pid 
                    HAVING proddate > Date('today') - 14
                    AND
                    site='"""+self.site[i]+"""'
                    AND
                    pid=802
                    AND
                    plant='"""+str(self.plant[j])+"""' 
                    ORDER BY proddate, site, plant, pid; 
                    """)

            self.row = self.cur.fetchone()

            while self.row:
                self.datProd1.append(self.row[0])
                self.datProd2.append(self.row[1])

                pylab.title('Progress of %s' %self.site[i])
                pylab.ylabel('number')
                pylab.xlabel('date')
                pylab.plot(self.datProd1, self.datProd2)
                pylab.savefig("bild%i" %i )

                self.row=self.cur.fetchone()

q = Datenanzeige()
q.anzeige()
```

the code is working. i get for every self.site variable another picture but every following picture includes the lines of the former one. how can i prevent this?
i need separate pictures without lines of the former one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, you need do one of two things:

1. use the `clf()` and `cla()` (clear figure and clear axes respectively) methods after you've saved your figures.
2. Create multiple [figures](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure), and then set the title and axes label on each figure. At the moment, you're using a default background figure that pylab gives you. You need to explicitly create and modify different ones. I can't write the exact code of the top of my head to do that, but a look at the [matplotlib api](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html) should give you what you are looking for. It will look something like this:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   fig = plt.figure()
   axes = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
   axes.set_xlabel("foo")
   axes.set_ylabel("bar")
   axes.set_title("title")
   # ...
   fig.savefig("filename")
   ```